# Is openGauss 3.1.1 fully compatible with PosgreSQL 14.2 in SQL syntax?

Tags: open-gauss

Is openGauss 3.1.1 fully compatible with PosgreSQL 14.2 in SQL syntax?

I tried some SQLs with different data types and all went well.

Answer (score 0):

openGauss forked off from Postgresql 9.2.x so the syntax is mostly the same. You can use most Postgresql resources to lookup the correct syntax, or you can use the [official documentation for openGauss 3.1.1](https://docs.opengauss.org/en/docs/3.1.1/docs/Developerguide/sql-reference.html).